# Have enter behave as key_down in QAbstractTableModel tableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using a QAbstractTableModel in PyQt5 and Qt Designer to create a data table. I need a little help to find a simple way to make the "Enter" keyPressEvent to move down the table as if the Key_Down button was pressed. The following code captures the Enter key press event. How do I make it move the cursor?

I have searched the forums and googled this problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet. I have tried creating a custom event to pass that along in place of 'ev', but that didn't work.

```py
def keyPressEvent(self, ev):        
    if ev.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
        print("Enter key pressed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the new `QModelIndex` using the `moveCursor()` method, and set the new selection using the `setCurrentIndex()` method of the `selectionModel()`.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
            index = self.moveCursor(
                QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MoveDown, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier
            )
            command = self.selectionCommand(index, event)
            self.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index, command)
        else:
            super(TableView, self).keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(10, 4)
    w = TableView()
    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you are using Qt Designer there are 2 possible implementations:

1. Promote the QTableView for use in Qt Designer.
2. Implement the logic using an eventFilter.

In this case I will show how to implement the second method:

```py
class EventFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super(EventFilter, self).__init__(view)
        if not isinstance(view, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            raise TypeError("{} must be a QAbstractItemView".format(view))
        self._view = view
        self._view.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self._view and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
                index = self._view.moveCursor(
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MoveDown, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier
                )
                command = self._view.selectionCommand(index, event)
                self._view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index, command)
        return super(EventFilter, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

And then you set it in your QTableView:

```py
event_filter = EventFilter(self.tableView)
```